# Criar Formulário / Tela HTML com coordenada do Banco de Dados

Tags: php, java, html, cliente-servidor

Boa Noite, Minha Duvida é o seguinte, possui um sistema onde toda a regra de negocio e o sistema em si está em banco de dados (SQL) inclusive as tela, relatórios, etc, porem ele possui um client para acessar, hoje ele ja é web, pois fica num servidor e por esse client o sistema é acessado, porem quero transformar esse sistema em Web/HTML, sendo acessado pelo browser, porem tenho dificuldade de entender como criar um formulario HTML com a tela que irei extrair do banco, ou seja, farei um select via webservice que me retornara os componentes da minha tela, label, edit, botão, grid, etc, como escrever um codigo para transformar isso em HTML, existe alguma ferramenta que realiza isso, se necessário poderei passar mais informações.
Obrigado

Comment: Não ficou claro o que você tem nesse banco de dados. Você diz que as telas estão armazenadas no banco, mas ao mesmo tempo você quer gerar HTML a partir delas, não seria o caso de apenas servi-las? Quais são os tipos de dados que você recebe do client/service mencionado? São arquivos no formato JSON? HTML?

Comment: Boa Tarde! Esclarecendo: No Meu Banco eu tenho uma tabela Dialogos, outra tabela componente, e eu guarda a estrutura da o meu dialogo em coordenada, por exemplo, o Dialogo tem 1000 X 800 px, está apoiado na tabela X, agora na tabela componente eu tenho os botões e campos que serã vinculado no dialogo, então o meu client solicita essas informações para o server e o server retorna um json, e o client monta a tela, entendeu. Agora eu quero converter essa engenharia em HTML, tentando aproveitar as telas, e não ter que redesenhar tudo. se precisar de informação contate, esorocaba@gmail.com, Obg.